# How to display ul and li vertically at the same line

Tags: html, css

I have this code :

```
<ul class="a">
  <li class="b">hhhh</li>
    <ul class="c">
      <li class="d">Home</li>
      <li class="d">hsos</li>
    <ul class="c">
      <li class="b">Home</li>
      <li class="b">Home</li>
    </ul>
```

When i display it the second li has a margin by default.  What i want is  that all that list to have the same margin.

Comment: Note that your HTML is incorrect.  You're child `<ul>` needs to be inside the `<li>`.  The only direct child of a `<ul>` can be a `<li>`. http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ad4jq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default `padding-right` in `ul` elements that you can remove using this CSS class:

```
ul {
   padding-left:0;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Jt2M/)

Comment: yes i will , i'm waiting 10 min because i can't Mark it as answered until 1O min pass i guess . do you know please how can i make the second li i mean the child a deferent color.

Comment: @user3546035 : `.d{/*your properties*/}`